# Component lifecycle

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

Below is an example that creates a simple component. 
According to http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#component-lifecycle it's possible to add a `dispose` function that get's invoked by ko when the component is removed from the DOM. I'm looking for something similar that would allow me to hook into **step 5 The component is active**.

#### additional info as requested by comment

In the example below I'd like to a) insert the DOM fragment created by the `ko component` and b) once it's attached to the DOM convert the `<ul>` into a kendo PanelBar. This is pretty similar to the way it could be done using Durandal's `compositionComplete` event. There are  probably other solutions, but I'm interested to see how/if this could be accomplished by using knockout components.

#### template

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       <ul class="panelBar" data-bind="foreach: widgets">
          <li data-bind="text: text"></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### viewModel

```
var widgets = [
    {
        text: 'Options'
    },
    {
        text: 'Pages'
    }
];

function FeaturePanel(params){
    this.widgets = ko.observableArray(widgets);
}

function createViewModel ( params, componentInfo ) {

   return new FeaturePanel(params);
}

module.exports = {
    createViewModel: createViewModel
};
```

Comment: What do you want to do this "active" hook? Can you describe your original problem/goal? Maybe there is a different solution exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I'm not the only, who wants to hook into the `active` event, but currently this is not supported by knockout. However there's a feature request for 3.3+
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1475